# Having a deeplink automatically direct to the Google Play Store or Apple App store depending on the device type

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking

We will be sending, via SMS, a link to some of our clients that links them to the Google Playstore or Appstore to download our app.

If the user already has our app installed, the link prompts a "Open with ABC app?" message when clicked.

We want to use a single link, meaning it should somehow automatically pick up device type. Meaning if the user doesn't have our app installed, it appropriately redirects them to the app or playstore.

Our devs are insisting that using a single link is impossible, just trying to make sure this is really the case as I don't recall a lot of apps sending 2 separate links to download from.

Comment: You can certainly do it.  It requires a bit of work on your web site to identify the incoming browser and then redirect to the universal link (iOS) or app link (Android). You might want to use a commercial service like https://branch.io/what-is-deep-linking/ or https://app.urlgeni.us

Comment: here is a tutorial on universal links for iOS - https://www.raywenderlich.com/6080-universal-links-make-the-connection a simple google search should lead you to something similar in android as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Our devs are insisting that using a single link is impossible

I think your devs are trying to avoid work :P

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links

Comment: The service will shut down on August 25, 2025, What now? :/

Comment: Now you read the Deprecation FAQs they link to and follow the instructions to find a solution that works for your use case.